# Hide li that contains specific text with javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, html-lists, hide

I'm trying to hide subcategories in a search drop-down menu in wordpress by specific text using javascript. so far without luck. I'm no programer so i'll appreciate your help with directions or fix to the script.
The menu html looks somewhat like this when i inspect the page(i've narrowed it down):

```html
<ul>
<li>
<select class="default-select select2-hidden-accessible" name="categories" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value=""> choose category </option>
<option value="119">Customer Support</option>
<option value="163">Hosting</option>
<option value="181"> - Link Building</option>
</li>
</ul>
```

When I inspect the options i get this:

```html
    <span class="select2-results">
    <ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-categories-85-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
    <li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> choose category </li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-categories-85-result-5nsl-119" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Customer Support</li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-categories-85-result-td3l-163" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Hosting</li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-categories-85-result-c6bv-181" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> - Link Building</li>
    </ul></span>
```

I'm trying to hide every li that contain the character "-" or "--".
so after a lot of searching i found this javascript:

```js
let lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let x = 0; x < lis.length; x++) {
    let li = lis[x];
    let content = li.textContent;
  
    if (content.indexOf('-') !== -1 || content.indexOf('--') !== -1) {
    li.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

The problem with this is when i use it the category menu disappears completely, and the category menu html code looks like this:

```html
<ul>
<li style="display: none;">
<select class="default-select select2-hidden-accessible" name="categories" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value=""> choose category </option>
<option value="119">Customer Support</option>
<option value="163">Hosting</option>
<option value="181"> - Link Building</option>
</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried using "getElementsByClassName('select2-results__option')" but it does absolutely nothing, like the menu and its content is not affected.
how can i fix this? Appreciate your help.

EDIT:
HTML PHP snippet of search section if it helps:

```html
<ul>
<li>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo __( 'What are you looking for?', 'exertio_theme' ); ?>" class="form-control" name="title" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title_value); ?>">
</div>
</li>
<li>
<select class="default-select" name="categories">
<option value=""> <?php echo __( 'Select Category', 'exertio_theme' ); ?> </option>
<?php echo get_hierarchical_terms('service-categories','', $cat_value ); ?>
</select>
</li>
<li> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-style btn-block"><?php echo __( 'Search', 'exertio_theme' ); ?></button> </li>
</ul>
```

in addition, when i use the following css to hide specific li in the drop-down menu it works (if that helps):

```
.select2-results__options > li:nth-child(2) { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has some syntax errors. You miss a `</select>` and I fixed this.
As you have different html source and I am not sure which one you are using.
I just take the first html source.

I updated your js files and the example below:

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll("option");

for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  const content = options[i].textContent;
  if (content.indexOf("-") !== -1 || content.indexOf("--") !== -1) {
    options[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

document
  .querySelector("select[name='categories']")
  .addEventListener("change", function () {
    const lis = document.querySelectorAll("span.select2-results li");

    for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
      const content = lis[i].textContent;
      if (content.indexOf("-") !== -1 || content.indexOf("--") !== -1) {
        lis[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <select
        class="default-select select2-hidden-accessible"
        name="categories"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <option value="">choose category</option>
        <option value="119">Customer Support</option>
        <option value="163">Hosting</option>
        <option value="181">- Link Building</option>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="select2-results">
    <ul
      class="select2-results__options"
      role="tree"
      id="select2-categories-85-results"
      aria-expanded="true"
      aria-hidden="false"
    >
      <li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">
        choose category
      </li>
      <li
        class="select2-results__option"
        id="select2-categories-85-result-5nsl-119"
        role="treeitem"
        aria-selected="false"
      >
        Customer Support
      </li>
      <li
        class="select2-results__option"
        id="select2-categories-85-result-td3l-163"
        role="treeitem"
        aria-selected="false"
      >
        Hosting
      </li>
      <li
        class="select2-results__option"
        id="select2-categories-85-result-c6bv-181"
        role="treeitem"
        aria-selected="false"
      >
        - Link Building
      </li>
    </ul></span
  >
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! thank you so much but unfortunately it didn't have effect. i can see the script on the page in html when i inspect, what am i doing wrong? also i updated my question with html-php snippet at the end of the post if you could check it out. much appreciated.

Comment: @alexnusinov, I try to update my answer. I hope it works now. I am actually confused because you have two HTML with different structures of options. One is list the item in ```li``` element. One is list in ```option``` element

Comment: first, thank you. wow, ok something is working with your updated script, now when i inspect the page in html all `option` sub-categories with '-' and '--' text now contain `style="display: none;"` which is exactly what i was trying to achieve, but i still see these sub-categories in the drop-down menu. i guess it is because there's 2 lists like you mentioned? i'm also confused by this logic(bought this theme). i've tried to duplicate your script and change `option` to `li` but that didn't have any effect, do you have any suggestions about the `li` list? thanks again.

Comment: i understand why there's no effect on the `li` list when i modify your script. the `li` menu only appears in html when drop-down menu is selected, the `li` appears at the very end of the page just before `</body>` and after the script, so it's dynamic. i'll keep digging trying to solve this but i believe your script works perfectly so thank you i really appreciate you helping me. have a good one!

Comment: @alexnusinov, That's a good hint for me. I updated my answer. I add a addEventlistener on the select element. whenever there is a change in the select element, it will hide the ```li``` which appears after you select an option. I hope it works now.

Comment: I'm learning a lot from you, still the update didn't remove the `li`. after digging all day i found that when i select the category drop-down menu there's a parent `span` element of the menu (that i didn't include in my question) that changes its class when clicking the menu and only when the drop-down menu is open it adds the `li` items under completely separately span element before the </body>. i looked for an event that can listen when attribute of element is changed, no luck. i'll try to fix this by editing the source js files. Again, Thank you for helping me and sharing your knowledge

Comment: @alexnusinov, you are welcome. You can try to upload the html you found out. I can have a look later tomorrow for you.

Comment: hey, solved the problem by editing .js file. i've updated the question with the solution that worked for me. thank you for helping me along the way.

Comment: @alexnusinov, Great to hear. You can answer your own question and accepted it yourself instead of updating the question. It helps people to see the question which is solved more clearly.

Comment: just did. peace out brother.

Answer (score 1):

managed to solve the problem, Thanks to @ikhvjs for providing scripts and helping i learned alot. i'll share solution if anyone is interested.

wordpress javascript file name: select2.full.min.js

The javascript that generated category items dynamically to the page is the following:

```js
    i.prototype.option=function(e){
    var t=document.createElement("li");
    t.className="select2-results__option";
    var n={role:"option","aria-selected":"false"},i=window.Element.prototype.matches||window.Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector||window.Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
    for(var r in(null!=e.element&&i.call(e.element,":disabled")||null==e.element&&e.disabled)&&(delete n["aria-selected"],n["aria-disabled"]="true"),null==e.id&&delete n["aria-selected"],null!=e._resultId&&(t.id=e._resultId),e.title&&(t.title=e.title),e.children&&(n.role="group",n["aria-label"]=e.text,delete n["aria-selected"]),n){
    var o=n[r];
    t.setAttribute(r,o)
    }
    if(e.children){
    var s=h(t),a=document.createElement("strong");
    a.className="select2-results__group";
    h(a);
    this.template(e,a);
    for(var l=[],c=0;c<e.children.length;c++){
    var u=e.children[c],d=this.option(u);
    l.push(d)
    }
    var p=h("<ul></ul>",{class:"select2-results__options select2-results__options--nested"});
    p.append(l),s.append(a),s.append(p)
    }
    else this.template(e,t);
    return f.StoreData(t,"data",e),t
    }
```

i simply added the following variable and if condition after the first variable declaration in the function:

```
var content=e.text;if(window.location.href.indexOf("/services-search/")!=-1&&(content.indexOf("-")!==-1||content.indexOf("--")!==-1)){t.style.display="none";}
```

now when i'm in the "/services-search/" page the sub categories that include "-" or  "--" do not display.